# How to compare two products produced by different objects

Tags: grammaticality, ambiguity

I have made a sentence like:

> A produced by B is better than A produced by C.

Can I change it to:

> A produced by B is better than C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Because you'd be comparing A and C.

If you want to shorten the sentence, try going to an active voice.

> "B produces A better than C does."

Comment: can I use *B produces more accurate A than C*?

Comment: Are you saying that A is a more accurate thing when produced by B, or that B is more accurate in the process of making A?  Are you comparing the result or the process?  If result, "B produces a more accurate A than C does".  If process, "B produces A more accurately than C does"

Comment: B and C are different methods. A are result produced by B and C with the same input.

Comment: "Equation X produces the square root of 2 more accurately than equation Y"

Comment: Excellent! That is exactly what I want!

Answer (score 0):

No, because you'd be comparing "A is produced by B" with "C", but it's not clear what "C" by itself means. Your first example avoids this problem by making a clear comparison between "A is produced by B" and "A is produced by C".

I agree with @JohnFeltz's rewording in the active voice. It's clear and shorter.